# visual studio code C/Cpp: Edit configurations does not open c_cpp_properties.json

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use visual studio code 1.18.1 with the plugin C/C++.
My system is XUBUNTU 16.04 32 bits

The command C/Cpp: Edit configurations does not open or create the file c_cpp_properties.json

Nothing happens

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you need to generate the c_cpp_properties.json file with the steps indicated in the below url.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_intellisense

As indicated in the step-3,

> *click Update "browse.path" setting*

should generate the file for you.

For your info, I dont have this problem and I use Ubuntu 14.01 with the visual studio code version 1.19.0.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It went away after I reinstalled the microsoft "C/C++" extension and temporarily removed the following two lines from my user settings.

```
//"C_Cpp.autocomplete": "Disabled",
//"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Disabled",
```

*fyi I have these because I found the `clangd` one, which so far is doing a much better job.

Answer (score 0):

I got it... I think it's all about **IntelliSense** for **C_Cpp**. After I re-enabled C_Cpp IntelliSense, **go to definition** works again...
Looks like different language has its own IntelliSense.

[image]